# Swapping string using bitwise operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

> Write a definition of the function bitwise_swap that uses only bit
>   wise assignment operators to swap the values of two strings.

I tried to iterate over each char, changing into an int and swapping
using

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Once I had the char int value but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: post detailed code showing what you tried, then we can help.

Comment: @Armin It doesn't matter whether they are equal ... I wonder where people get this idea, and why they don't have the mathematical intuition to reject it.

Comment: You don't have to iterate over each character just swap the addresses.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you attempted something like this, which should work fine.

```
void bitwise_swap(char * restrict lhs, char * restrict rhs, size_t length) {
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<length; ++i) {
        lhs[i] ^= rhs[i];
        rhs[i] ^= lhs[i];
        lhs[i] ^= rhs[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `i` be of type `size_t`? Also, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Aliasing `lhs` and `rhs` must not point to the same string.

Comment: @Alexandros: I had already fixed the size_t issue, but let's codify the other restriction that you've mentioned by marking the pointers as `restrict`.

Comment: For some reason or another `i` was still an `int`, so I changed it.

Comment: @Alexandros: Oops! When you said `i`, I read that as `length`. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <stdbool.h>

    int main()
    {  int m,n,t,i;
        char a[]="National University";
        char b[]="India";
        char c[100];
        char d[100];

        m=strlen(a);
        n= strlen(b);


        if(m>n)
        {   t=m;
         //   strcpy(&c,&a);
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
              d[i]=b[i];
            for(i=0;i<m-n;i++)
                d[n+i]=32;
            for(i=0;i<t;i++)
                   {
                    a[i]=a[i]^d[i];
                    d[i]=d[i]^a[i];
                    a[i]=a[i]^d[i];
                   }

            printf("a= %s \t b=%s" ,a,d);
        }
        else
        {   t=n;
       // strcpy(&d,&b);
           for(i=0;i<m;i++)
               c[i]=a[i];
           for(i=0;i<n-m;i++)
            c[m+i]=32;
           for(i=0;i<t;i++)
                {
                                c[i]=c[i]^b[i];
                                b[i]=b[i]^c[i];
                                c[i]=c[i]^b[i];
                            }

           printf("c= %s \t d=%s" ,c,b);
        }



    return 0;
    }
```

This way you can do it.You just need a loop for swapping each character.
EDIT: Now its dynamic. You need not to specify length manually and I am appending NULL character at the end of shorter string. Look result at :http://ideone.com/B7lsz4

Comment: it's accessed an array out of range

Comment: Did you try? For at least one implementation, it prints "a= Overflowack   b=owack": http://ideone.com/gFiYUg

Comment: I checked in eclipse and it works fine.
Check here:http://ideone.com/AuBADM

Comment: @mvv1277 what about this: http://ideone.com/5hpl0P Obviously you're accessing the shorter array out of bounds. It may seem to work sometimes on some implementations.

Comment: @Henrik You are right. Can you pls provide solution to this problem? because I tried to make program dynamic i.e. for any length of string not Like other solution where we have to manually pass the length.

Comment: You mean how to squeeze a string of length 8 into an array of length 6? Sorry, I don't have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Finally i made it 
http://ideone.com/B7lsz4